# Semantic UI labeled icon button of type submit button

Tags: html, input, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI and trying to add an icon to an input button type submit

This is my try:

```
<i class="sign in icon"></i>
<input type="submit" name="login-button" class="ui blue submit button" value="Login">
```

The problem is that the icon is displayed in front of the button and not inside the button.

This is how it can be done, with a div:

```
<div id="login-button" class="ui blue submit labeled icon button">
    <i class="sign in icon"></i> Login
</div>
```

Do you know any way to add an icon to a button type submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" name="login-button" class="ui blue submit button">
  <i class="sign in icon"></i>
  Login
</button>
```

Hope this helps.

W3 has this to say in regards to the button element:

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering possibilities: the BUTTON element may have content. For example, a BUTTON element that contains an image functions like and may resemble an INPUT element whose type is set to "image", but the BUTTON element type allows content.